# C two dimensional array input work, but output gives something other out

Tags: c, arrays, input

```
int main(int argc, char* arv[])
{

    int m;
    printf("How many Rows and Lines?:\n");
    scanf("%d", &m);
    char board[m][m] ;
    int rows, columns;
    for(rows = 0; rows < m; rows++)
    {
       for(columns = 0; columns < m; columns++)
        {
            char *board = malloc(rows*columns*sizeof(int));
        }
    }
    for(rows = 0; rows < m; rows++)
    {
        for(columns = 0; columns < m; columns++)
        {
            printf("%c", board[rows][columns]);
        }
        printf("\n");
    }
}
```

The Problem is that i evreytime get wrong output :/
If someone can help me it were nice, i am new at programming

Comment: In the first nested loop you are trying to allocate memory to the same variable multiple times with `char *board = malloc(rows*columns*sizeof(int));`. It is futile anyway, since `board` was already defined as an array, and the block scope `char *board` of the same name becomes invalid after the loop.

Comment: in addition to the shadowing mentioned in the answer (and the memory leak), what output were you expecting? You never assign any values to `board`, the output is going to be junk data. `malloc` does not initialize memory to any specific values

Comment: when calling any of the `scanf()` family of functions, always check the returned value (not the parameter value) to assure the operation was successful.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do you just want to initialize the array? It's already created outside the loops and you don't need to allocate the memory again. This:

```
for(rows = 0; rows < m; rows++)
{
   for(columns = 0; columns < m; columns++)
    {
        board [rows][columns]='a';
    }
}
```

In place of the first nested loop will give this as result:

```
How many Rows and Lines?:
5
aaaaa
aaaaa
aaaaa
aaaaa
aaaaa
```

Answer (score 1):

the `board` inside the first loop has scope restricted to that loop. You are not modifying the array you declared at the beginning of the function.

What do you want to put inside the array?

Answer (score 0):

As people said, your `board` inside the loop is completely unrelated to the one outside, so any change performed on it won't be reflected. From  that, the reason that at every time you get something different it is because the actual `board` is not initialized and can take casual values.